# How to align left just a single sentence in a justified paragraph in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am pretty much new to Illustrator and I stumble upon a problem (for me) on the text area. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see I have justified the whole paragraph, but the last sentence with only 2 words are looking fairly awkward, so I want it to align left. The problem is that when I click align left while the last sentence is highlighted, the whole paragraph aligns left.

Gurus, what should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the justified, flush left option in the **Paragraph Panel** and *not* the force justify option.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Its kinda frustrating I didn't saw that option. Thanks mate!